# How do I clear location.state in react-router on page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am currently passing my state on route change like below:

```
<Link to={{
           pathname:`/transactions/${props.transaction.id}`,
           state: {transaction: props.transaction}
         }}> View Details </Link>
```

My logic is that if "location.state.transaction" exists, don't fetch new data, else, fetch data.

Now the flaw is when there is a page reload. The application needs to fetch new data if the user reloads the page. I thought "location.state" would get cleared if there is a reload, but apparently the state is saved in sessionStorage.

How do I work around this? 
I could just fetch new data every time, but it should not fetch data when the 'View Details' Link is clicked.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you're using react hooks, you can use `window.history` directly to clear the state without triggering a rerender. This is better than using the `useHistory` hook's `replace` method, which would cause your component to rerender.

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '')
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This does need any 3rd party lib and doesn't reload the browser as well. Thanks a lot @frodo2975

Comment: Thanks. But why to pass `document.title` as the second parameter? According to MDN docs, "This parameter exists for historical reasons, and cannot be omitted; passing the empty string is traditional": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

Comment: It looks like really old versions of Safari used to display the 2nd argument as the page's title, but this isn't a concern for modern browsers. I'm going to go ahead and edit this to use the empty string.

Answer (score 25):

I also ran into this problem, and what I ended up doing was retrieving the browser history from react router and clearing specific location.state properties. So in your case, it would be `transaction`. I did this in `componentDidMount` so that after the first time you go to the page, that property should no longer be there,

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

...

componentDidMount(){
    const history = createHistory();
    if (history.location.state && history.location.state.transaction) {
        let state = { ...history.location.state };
        delete state.transaction;
        history.replace({ ...history.location, state });
    }
}
```

Comment: nice solution!!

Comment: a @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE is dispatched. but the state stays the same

Answer (score 23):

There is better approach without using the 3 party library.

We can use `history.replace()`

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md

```
componentDidMount(){
 const {location,history} = this.props;
 //use the state via location.state
 //and replace the state via
 history.replace() 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In react Router V6 you can use useNavigate() to clear state for current path:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
useEffect(() => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate(location.pathname, {}); 
  // reload and pass empty object to clear state
  // we can also use replace option: ..., {replace: true}
}, []);
```

Comment: What if you display things based on location.state? eg. ``location.state.bananas === "bananas" ? "more bananas" : "no bananas for you" `` will always produce the latter because ``useEffect()`` will reload the whole thing

Comment: This worked better for me than the accepted answer. I have a reusable breadcrumb component that just parses the URL but displays a crumbTitle if its sent via state and wanted to keep that, but I also sent a string that caused a modal to open. I didn't want the modal to reopen on refresh but I wanted to retain the crumbTitle otherwise it would display the ID from url params. I was able to update the state the way I wanted to and retain the crumbTitle with this solution. I am not sure why the accepted answer doesn't work for this scenario.

Comment: I also just found out you can pass an empty string instead of location.pathname.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. The various suggestions of history.replace or history.useReplace did not work.  This line did the trick: `navigate(location.pathname, { replace: true })`

Answer (score 5):

After you used the state, dispatch an action with an empty state again to clean the state.

```
this.props.dispatch(replace({
  ...this.props.location,
  state: undefined
});
```

Comment: underrated answer

Answer (score 3):

`history.replace({ state: {} })`.
If you also want to redirect user somewhere then use `history.replace({ pathname: '/profile/me', state: {} })`

Answer (score 2):

In **React Router v6** you can do:

```js
const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const state = location.state;
// Do some stuff with the state
// ...

// Clear the state after
navigate(location.pathname, { replace: true });
```

Navigating to current page won't do any visible effect other than clearing the state (modifing history).

Answer (score 1):

This is what might work.

```
const history = useHistory();
// consume the history.location.state and reset the state
useEffect(() => {
    history.replace(`/transactions/${history.location.state.transaction.id}`, {});
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use the `location` prop here, but to create a Route (wherever you define them) with a path: `/transactions/:transactionId`, and to catch the `transactionId` in the prop `props.match.params.transactionId` inside of the target component. Then in the `componentDidMount` you can dispatch the API request action in order to fetch the transaction. Don't forget to delete the `state` param from the props of the Link.

Answer (score -1):

None of these would reset my state using useNavigate.  What I had to do was set up a useEffect on navigate.

```
...
const navigate = useNavigate()
...

useEffect(() => {
  // set state here
  ....
},[navigate]
```